# Passing '&' as text in parameter in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments, vb6

I am trying to pass an argument to a BAT file thru VB Shell function. argument text value looks like this say `Hello&123`
As you noticed there's an '&' as text in it. However & is reserved in BAT so I am trying to make it work but so far unsuccessful.

My VB 6 code is

```
Dim passwd
passwd = "Hello^&123"
retval = Shell("C:\test.bat " & passwd, vbNormalFocus)
```

I have tried following combinations but none work. So I am clueless what value should I set to variable passwd in VB 6 that will accept Hello&123 as correct text parameter in BAT.

Errors I receive

passwd = "Hello^&123"

```
 Hello
'123' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

passwd = """Hello^&123"""

```
"Hello^&123"
```

passwd = "Hello&&123"

```
Hello
```

However none of the above are useful as I want %1 to be exactly as Hello&123

Any further help will be great.

Edit...

The batch file just now simply has echo command.

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
```

Thanks.

Comment: wrapping `&` in quotes work because [it loses the special meaning inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714). Probably the issue is in the way you're printing the variable. What's the content of the batch file?

Comment: The error is probably in the batch file. You are passing the parameter correctly but then the batch gets the ampersand. You need to escape it again for the batch file. Perhaps `^^^&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is probably in the batch file. You are passing the parameter correctly but then the batch gets the ampersand. You need to escape it again for the batch file. Perhaps `^^^&`.

`^` is the quote character so `^^` = `^`.

So to `cmd` gets `^^^&` and changes `^^` to `^` and `^&` to `&` so the end result is `^&`. When CMD reads your batch file it changes `^&` to `&`. So CMD needs to read this twice.

Quotes are often easier if typing at the prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Not the input should be changed, but the handling should.

> test.bat Hello^&123
>   ... or with quotes ...
>   test.bat "Hello&123"

```
@echo off

set "arg1=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo arg1=!arg1!
```

## Explanation

1. `%~1` strip quotes, when the argument is enclosed.
2. `set "arg=..."`
   is the extended SET syntax, it enclosed the content into quotes, but
   doesn't add the quotes to the variable.   `
3. echo ...!arg1!` used the
   delayed expansion, as delayed expansion can handle any content from
   variables without interpreting it.

Answer (score 1):

I am just using Answer space to show finally what worked. User Mark is right.

```
Dim passwd
passwd = "Hello^^^&123"
retval = Shell("C:\test.bat " & passwd, vbNormalFocus)
```

and the BAT file right now simply has

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
```

See the result now. To keep it simple I just invoking test.bat at command prompt.

[image]

Comment: You're using `echo %1` exactly as I guessed. The argument still contains the string `Hello^&123` as expected but when echoing the string `^` is a normal escape character so obviously it won't work